# When background image with cover background-size, and position absolute stops resizing?

Tags: html, css

Let us assume we have an image set up as a background of the `div`. The `div` has `position: absolute`. The image is in `background-size: cover` mode. In this case the background image is going to be resized. But at some point, at some size the width, and height of the background image will be the same.

How to calculate at what size the image will stop resize?

It's not directly related to width, or height of the image, nor container. I was unable to find any documentation about it.

**CSS**

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("http://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/files/blogs/istock-unfinished-business-hed-2015.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/fbng74dm/

**Update**

Some example values (approximate):

- container height 976
- container stops resizing background image at width 1540

---

- container height 729
- container stops resizing background image at width 1147

---

- container height 643
- container stops resizing background image at width 1010

---

- background image height 2827
- background image width  4465

Comment: When you scale down (not up) at some point it stops resizing. After that point the image is cropped from right (you move window to make it smaller, and image doesn't resize, but it cut).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has a large width, the image is scaled and therefore one cannot see the full height of it. The more one reduces the size of the container, the greater the amount of the height that fits into the container becomes. Once one can see the full height, the image should not be resized anymore, since it would not cover the container then.

Why? Let us look at an example where we do not stop resizing the background image:

```js
var aspectRatio = 1920 / 1280;
var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[0];
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);

function resizeListener() {
 if (bg.offsetWidth / bg.offsetHeight <= aspectRatio) {
   bg.className = 'bg small';
  } else {
   bg.className = 'bg';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("http://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/files/blogs/istock-unfinished-business-hed-2015.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}

.small {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
</div>
```

Try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akeo9dsw/)!

You see, the background image does not cover the whole background anymore, but we have set `background-size: cover;`. This is the reason why it retains its height and simply protrudes from the side.

When is this point reached? As you can already see in my code example, the point is reached once the aspect ratio of the container becomes smaller than the aspect ratio of the background image. The reason is trivial: There is no other possibility. Try it out, you will not be able to proceed differently. There are simply practical reasons for this.

Comment: I've just calculated aspect ratio. That's it. Great answer. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` queries to cause the background size to stop being `cover` when the screen reaches a certain width. For example:

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("http://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/files/blogs/istock-unfinished-business-hed-2015.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
@media(max-width: 600px){
  .bg{
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 601px){
  .bg{
     background-size:auto;
   }
}
```

This means *up to a maximum width of 600px* (i.e. when the window is 600px wide or less) the background will be `cover`, and *down to a minimum width of 601px* (i.e. when the window is 601px wide or more) the background will be `auto`.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not the answer to my question.